# Rendering a Report in SQL Server Reporting Services using SOAP API

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to render a report in SQL Server Reporting Services using SOAP API without specifying the format such that you get the report toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you code your own rendering extension. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606.aspx)  to start (Note the link is for SSRS 2008).